# How do I write a constructor for unknown number of parameters in java?

Tags: java, constructor

I'm basically making a class for each  university course where any number of students can apply. I wanted to know how can I have a constructor where it doesn't matter if my number of 'Student' objects is 1 or 15 or more...cause I know there's a way, just can't remember it...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Course {
    String name;
    ArrayList <Student>listofstudents=new ArrayList<>();
    int noofStudents;
    //The class Student is defined. 
    Course(String name,Student s1, Student s2){
        this.name=name;
        listofstudents.add(s1);
        listofstudents.add(s2);
        //Do I have to do this for every possible number of student?
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html "Arbitrary Number of Arguments"

Comment: You can have a  `Student[]`, a `Student`-[varargs parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html), `Collection<Student>` (with `Collection` being my favorite solution of those options). The question, though, is: why define all students at construction? Why not have methods to add and remove students from a course?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your other answer observes, constructors can have variable arguments just like regular methods can have.  However, you should consider just saying no.  That is, the students enrolled in a given course are a secondary attribute, and you can put a `Course` into a valid state without them.  Consider, then, not accepting the students via the constructor, but instead having one or more methods to add students to existing `Course`s.  (You might need that anyway.)  Then just add the students via that route after initializing the `Course`.

```
void addStudent(Student s) {
    listofstudents.add(s);
}

void addStudents(Student ... s) {
    if (s != null) {
        listofstudents.addAll(java.util.Arrays.asList(s));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use varargs. Variable Arguments is a technology that allows you to create methods with an arbitrary number of arguments.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Course {
    String name;
    ArrayList <Student>listofstudents=new ArrayList<>();
    int noofStudents;
    //The class Student is defined. 
    Course(String name,Student ... s){
        Student [] stds = s;
        this.name=name;
        //your code
    }
}
```

Varargs are straightforward to use. But there're a few rules we have to keep in mind:

- Each method can only have one varargs parameter
- The varargs argument must be the last parameter

**Every time we use varargs, the Java compiler creates an array to hold the given parameters.**

Now you can use the constructor in this way:

```
new Course("Name");
new Course("Name", new Student());
new Course("Name", new Student(), new Student(), new Student());
```

Comment: It should be noted that varargs behaves like an array and that a `Collection<...>` often fulfills the same job.

Comment: ...and a convenient way of creating such a collection is `Arrays.asList`, which itself uses a varargs parameter.